# Sure I will or I Sure will

Tags: will-future

If someone says to me

> Make sure to check this in future, next time you update this.

How should I reply?

1. *Sure I will*
   or
2. *I Sure will*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acceptable answers are :

> Sure, I will.
>
> I Surely will.
>
> I will, Surely check this in future